# java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'user'@'hostname' (using password: YES)

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Before I get into this I want to state I have read a few other posts on this issue and none of them helped.

I am trying to connect to a MySQL server using a user I know exists as well as the correct password, I am able to connect via PHPMYADMIN & directly through my servers terminal.

The code I'm using to connect:

```java
final String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
            final String url = "jdbc:mysql://external_ip_address_here:3306/dbname";
            final String username = "user";
            final String password = "pass";
            Class.forName(driver);

            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
```

Thank you for reading, I look forward to your potential solutions for this.

Comment: The most common scenario for this error is that the database does not have remote connection access

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem like a programatical error. Your user does not have permission for **remote** connection. Go through this [checklist](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html) in order to troubleshoot